# How does a foreigner's handwriting look to a native?

Tags: characters, handwriting

How do Chinese characters foreigners or beginner Chinese learners write appear to natives?  Is there a difference?  Does it depend on how long they have been learning, or are they all different from a native Chinese's handwriting?  Would the handwriting even strike a native as a foreigner's penning at all?  And how about a beginner's handwriting?

Alright, those are all my questions.

Comment: It is not a question that can be answered with fact. All beginners write horribly, a native Chinese 3 years old and a 60 years old non-Chinese man's writing might look the same in people's eyes. Once they get better at it, you can't tell the difference

Comment: I've heard of comparisons to Mao Xinyu's handwriting...

Comment: My advice: 1. Find a copybook for calligraphy. Kaishu(楷书, regular script) is the best choice. 2. Practise a lot and think the structure of Chinese Characters. How much should you practise? I don't know, but a lot of Chinese practises for years to write well. Actually, three years' practice is enough to write well for a Chinese learner, in my opinion.

Comment: Having taught a large number of adult foreigners, I can say that it's certainly not true that everybody starts on the same level. Some students show great penmanship in English and are able to write neat Chinese characters very quickly compared to others. Their characters might be wrong in some aspects, but don't look childish at all. Ultimately, it's about spending a lot of time on writing, taking your time and caring about what it looks like. Most people don't, so their handwriting is horrible.

Comment: Penmanship shows a person's artistic inclination and skill in balance, somebody just does not have any and never will, regardless of native or not, and intelligence or education level. BTW, I wonder how popular is for foreigners to learn "毛筆字":) It could be real benefits in learning Chinese writing though.

Comment: @Olle Linge Have you taught any student using the traditional Chinese brush? If so, do you notice that those who did tend to write better with other writing medium? My personal view is that using the brush would improve one's character writing skill owing to the absolute need to achieve consistently near perfect accuracy in every stroke. Perhaps taking up some rudimentary Chinese calligraphy might help?

Comment: @WayneCheah No, I haven't! I think this is almost non-existent for practical language courses these days. Even handwriting characters in the first place is put at lower priority, so it goes without saying that calligraphy is even further down the list. There are simply too many things to teach to consider small benefits calligraphy might have on handwriting. Sad, but true!

Comment: @OlleLinge I think you need to learn the "eight-ways" (永字八法), which forms the base of proper Chinese writing and can't be learned using tools other than the brush (毛筆).

Comment: @r13: I don't see the connection to the question here, could you clarify, maybe? And when you say "you", who do you mean? The students?

Comment: @OlleLinge Although you don't need to teach handwriting class, you still have to write Chinese on the blackboard, don't you? You is simply you, no other meaning.

Comment: @r13 I asked about "you" because it's often used in a generic sense. I'm still not entirely clear what you're trying to convey. Why do you say that I need to learn 永字八法? What makes you think I don't already know it? Do you mean "teach" when you say "learn", maybe? All I said above was that in a modern foreign-language context, handwriting is often not at the top of the priority list and calligraphy is focused on even less.

Comment: @OlleLinge Yeah, in a "Practical Conversation" class, the writing part is not that important to you or your student, but I wouldn't call it a "Practical Language" class, which includes "Read, Speak and Write".

Comment: It depends. The traditional Chinese "brush" is harder to handle than modern writing tools. Then there are inherited differences. Some people have a natural flair to handwriting. My mother has a much better handwriting than my father even though they are around the same age, so they have more or less the same amount of practice. So the answer to your question is no. A foreigner might just have the natural ability to write nicely in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

It does require a lot of effort. Some native speakers of Mandarin Chinese might write worse than non-natives. It all depends on how much time and effort you'd like to put in. First, find the writing you like, and just copy it as many times as it takes for you to write the same thing. It's the same as practice calligraphy really.

As a native of Taiwan, we write traditional characters. And I seriously cannot remember how many times I wrote the characters while learning... A LOT for sure.

Answer (score 0):

How do Chinese characters foreigners or beginner Chinese learners write appear to natives?

Weird yet right.

Is there a difference? Does it depend on how long they have been learning, or are they all different from a native Chinese's handwriting?

Knowing the basics is what it takes to achieve writing Chinese. Lines and curves are the most important thing to keep in mind. There are different writings in Chinese, just like English. Cursive is one of them. Time is a huge impact. Have you heard of this saying: Practice makes perfect.

Would the handwriting even strike a native as a foreigner's penning at all? And how about a beginner's handwriting?

Shrug. Foreigner penning and beginner penning is almost like the same thing but with different practice. Even a Native would need to begin with the same method of writing. I know because I'm Chinese and learn this from painful writing experiences like writing a word 500 times before I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

There is no true difference.

In general, foreigners will have worse or slightly off handwriting.  However this is because of less time practicing writing chinese by hand, or not learning proper techniques.  You will also see natives who haven't had as much writing practice or learned improper techniques. These people with poor writing are indistinguishable as foreigner or native-- they are all equally "incorrect" or "lacking practice".  Think of any native english speaker you know with not beautiful or even straight up illegible handwriting-- it can happen to anyone.

In the same way, there are plenty of foreigners who have put in the time to practice handwriting and learned proper techniques.  There handwriting will be indistinguishable from a natives, maybe even above average if its nice and legible.

At the end of the day, writing is its own skill, seperate from ability to read or speak or other language abilities.  Consider that everyday, our modern world moves more and more to typing, making writing less and less important. This lowers everyone's handwriting ability, and the lines become blurrier and blurrier everyday (literally lol).

Even so, anyone willing to put in the hundreds of hours of practice can achieve calligraphy level beautiful handwriting-- english or chinese, native or foreigner(･̑◡･̑)

Answer (score -1):

It is almost impossible. As a native, I was still be required to have the practice in my senior high school by my teacher. Do not give up. Have your paractice patiently and regularly. Maybe 5 years or 8 years, you will find your own way to write every character. And when you find that your same Chinese characters look almost same, then you might begin to have native handwriting. For now, just keep your handwriting clear and neat.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about what handwriting from different types of learners looks like to native speakers.